# PHP SQLite Admin is running on PHP 5.4

Tags: sqlite

I tried [phpsqliteadmin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpsqliteadmin/)

But it doesn't seem to work anymore on PHP 5.4.

There are several alternatives, but none of them seems to be "The One" that is maintained and widely used.

Is there a standard SQLite admin webinterface, (preferably installable via apt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this one](https://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/) instead, it appears to be more active than the one you're using.
Another very active project for such tools with SQLite is [here](http://www.adminer.org/). Your tool hasn't been updated for over a year - that's usually a sign that the project is oprhanware.

Comment: cool, with [phpliteadmin](https://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/) I could manage my owncloud SQLite database `/var/www/owncloud/data/owncloud.db`. (I copied the database into the phpliteadmin folder for a start)